# Plotting very long signals without aliasing

Tags: graphs, plotting

Does anyone know of a free program or library that is capable of plotting very long periodic signals (like audio), say 1 billion points, interactively (so I can zoom/pan) and *without aliasing* when you zoom out.

Matlab is not bad at this, but is obviously far from free. Audacity is also ok but makes no attempt to prevent aliasing. In fact I think it just sub-samples the data.

[This site](http://blog.hvidtfeldts.net/index.php/2011/07/plotting-high-frequency-functions-using-a-gpu/) explains the aliasing problem rather well (see also [this demo](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/4sB3zz)). Unfortunately those demos only work because they are plotting functions. I want to plot data.

I've tried all the common Python/Julia/Gnuplot/R/Qt/etc. plotting libraries but none of them are really designed for plotting more than a few thousand points.

Any OS, though preferably OSX. Windows OK too. Any language. Ideally free but if there's a really good solution that isn't insanely expensive that would be interesting too. Don't care too much about licence but opens source is obviously preferable.

Comment: It is very hard to show 1 bil points without any kind of summarization (aliasing is one of them, but there are several)
-many of them would be on the same pixel
-would consume lots of RAM and VRAM
-scaling and panning would consume lots of cycles

Comment: The way to do this is to have a program pre-filter data and store it in a hierarchical structure, selecting from the most suitably filtered data depending on the zoom level. The graphical analogy is called [mipmap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mipmap) and is used in computer games to display textures that are very far away. This is conceptually easy, someone just has to do it. I hope someone will post an answer with a tool that can do this.